# Issue in fetching record from database in php

Tags: php, database

Hello guys [this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwInr.png) and i need to display data in such a way that i want to show sum of `total_cost` only but only if `final_amount` is '0', if `final_amount` is not '0' then it should be get added to `total_cost`.

**for example**
the sum of vendor_id=100 is 1100 that is (500[final_amount is not 0]+300+300)

Please help me

Comment: see the image you will get clear picture

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and then calculate full cost in php.

```
 "SELECT `total_cost` FROM `test` WHERE `final_amount` = 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working fine. [SQL Fiddle Here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7c106/1)

```
SELECT SUM( 
  CASE WHEN final_amount !=0
     THEN final_amount
  ELSE total_cost
  END ) AS total
 FROM test
 WHERE vendor_id =100
```